# Is it possible for a PHPUnit test to receive data from separate providers at the same time?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, testng-dataprovider

I know I can do this:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider validInputWithGatewayProvider
 */

public function it_cancels_subscription( string $gateway, array $input ) {
   
   $this
      ->actingAs( $this->createSubscriber() )
      ->withHeaders( [ 'X-Gateway' => $gateway ] )
      ->postJson( $this->route, $input )
      ->assertStatus(200)

}

public function validInputWithGatewayProvider() {
   return [
      [ 
         'paypal' => [ 
            'paypal',
            [ 'subscriptionId' => 'I-XXXX' ]
         ]
      ],
      [
         'stripe' => [ 
            'stripe',
            [ 'subscriptionId' => 'sub_xxxx' ]
         ]
      ],
   ]
}

public function invalidInputWithGatewayProvider() {
   return [
      [ 
         'paypal' => [ 
            'paypal',
            [ 'subscriptionId' => 'invalidId' ]
         ]
      ],
      [
         'stripe' => [ 
            'stripe',
            [ 'subscriptionId' => 'invalidId' ]
         ]
      ],
   ]
}
```

but I would like to provide the gateway and the input from separate providers, because as you can see in this way I have to add the gateway again in `invalidInputWithGatewayProvider` for invalid input tests. Ideally, I could do something like this:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider gatewayProvider
 * @dataProvider validInputProvider
 */

public function it_cancels_subscription( string $gateway, array $input ) {
   
   $this
      ->actingAs( $this->createSubscriber() )
      ->withHeaders( [ 'X-Gateway' => $gateway ] )
      ->postJson( $this->route, $input )
      ->assertStatus(200)

}

public function gatewayProvider() {
   return [
      [ 'paypal' => 'paypal' ],
      [ 'stripe' => 'stripe' ],
   ]
}

public function validInputProvider() {
   return [
      [ 
         'paypal' => [ 'subscriptionId' => 'I-XXXX' ]
      ],
      [
         'stripe' => [ 'subscriptionId' => 'sub_xxxx' ]
      ],
   ]
}

public function invalidInputProvider() {
   return [
      [ 
         [ 'subscriptionId' => 'invalidId' ]
      ]
   ]
}
```

however the above doesn't do what I'm looking for, because it runs the test once with `gatewayProvider`, and then again with `validInputProvider`, so the provided data is always passed to the test as the first parameter.

Of course I can have separate providers and then create a 'middleware' function that merges them into a single provider etc. but I was wondering if there is an easier, built-in solution.

Comment: As the [documentation (v10) shows](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.1/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-data-providers-examples-numericdatasetstest-php), it will always run each provider, one at a time, so no, you cannot "mix them", what yuo could do is use a `collection` and mix everything with `crossJoin`, but it may be hardear to read if you did not code that, so I would just manually write the test. Remember a test must not be overengineered, it is a test, do not set a lot of definitios, else you will have to also maintain a test (double work), that is not the idea...